# Why does DELETE FROM ... FROM ... not error out?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This bit within a stored proc is apparently valid sql:

```
DELETE TOP (@MaxRecords)
FROM Table
FROM Table B
INNER JOIN Table2 R ON B.fk = R.pk
WHERE R.Value < @DecVariable;
```

How can two FROM statements be put together and yet still be valid?

Comment: change tag from mysql to **sql**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `TOP` in delete syntax indicates that it is **SQL Server**.

It is perfect valid query, see [`DELETE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx):

> **FROM**
>
> An optional keyword that can be used between the DELETE keyword and the target table_or_view_name, or rowset_function_limited.
>
> **FROM table_source**
>
> Specifies an additional FROM clause. This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE allows specifying data from  and deleting the
>   corresponding rows from the table in the first FROM clause.
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can be used instead of a subquery in the WHERE clause to identify rows to be removed.

**DELETE:**
[image]

**Object:**
[image]

Comment: Interesting! I did not know this. Thanks.

Comment: @user1729696 Keep in mind that it is SQL Server specific syntax.

Comment: That is indeed what I am using. I will mark this as the answer when I am allowed to.