# How to scale with numbers table - exploding the memory and the hard disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to populate a half fulfilled column with some values for some dates and having NULL for the rest.

- The task is a basic fill in the gaps with the value of previous row. 
  It needs n iterations to fill the entire table. 
  I am using NUMBERS table to do the iterations and it works for small sample table like the following.
- When it is done for 18 mn rows data, it cannot finish the query because it explodes computer resources and runtime is endless. How to scale this?

Or are there any better ways to do it? This solution seemed good for me at first.

'As is' and to be [statusTEST] column as follows:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ SOZLESMENO ║ tDuration ║  YRMONTH   ║ statusTest_AsIs ║ statusTest_ToBE ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║   40000001 ║         0 ║ 2010-01-01 ║ 1               ║               1 ║
║   40000001 ║         1 ║ 2010-02-01 ║ NULL            ║               1 ║
║   40000001 ║         2 ║ 2010-03-01 ║ NULL            ║               1 ║
║   40000001 ║         3 ║ 2010-04-01 ║ NULL            ║               1 ║
║   40000001 ║         4 ║ 2010-05-01 ║ 2               ║               2 ║
║   40000001 ║         5 ║ 2010-06-01 ║ NULL            ║               2 ║
║   40000001 ║         6 ║ 2010-07-01 ║ NULL            ║               2 ║
║   40000001 ║         7 ║ 2010-08-01 ║ NULL            ║               2 ║
║   40000001 ║         8 ║ 2010-09-01 ║ 3               ║               3 ║
║   40000001 ║         9 ║ 2010-10-01 ║ NULL            ║               3 ║
║   40000001 ║        10 ║ 2010-11-01 ║ NULL            ║               3 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

I use the following code with predefined Numbers table of 10,000 rows

```
--Numbers table defined
SELECT TOP 10000 H = IDENTITY(INT, 0, 1)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a
CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns b;

--Alternating the table H times to get statusTest_toBE column shown above
DECLARE @iteration_limit INT = 60

UPDATE X
SET X.statusTest = (
        CASE 
            WHEN X.statusTest IS NOT NULL THEN X.statusTest
            ELSE Y.statusTest
        END
        )
FROM 
           [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton X 
CROSS JOIN [Mainfiles].dbo.Numbers3 N
LEFT JOIN  [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton Y 
       ON (X.SOZLESMENO = Y.SOZLESMENO)
      AND (DATEADD(MONTH, - N.H, X.YRMONTH) = Y.YRMONTH)
      AND N.H BETWEEN 1 AND @iteration_limit
```

Comment: @lad2025 how you did that table format?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have specific set of tools for enhanced SO experience :) Let's call it magic

Comment: @lad2025 would you share some of those?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sure http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html enjoy :)

Comment: @lad2025 Cool, thanks for the clear format :) Guys I need to pick your brains on this, going crazy here.

Comment: @EMRE Im trying to understand your query but not sure what does

Comment: @EMRE Probably your LOG file grows to much. I suggest doing UPDATE in chunks for example per 10k rows in WHILE LOOP

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041791/why-does-delete-from-from-not-error-out/33041916#33041916 for more magic :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza,  know the query is a bit odd, If you focus on how to get the toBE status column in other ways, that also is super fine for me. Maybe I am doing something super complicated where it is not necessary.  How would you fill in the gaps? Should be the appropriate question I think

Comment: @lad2025 would using a 10k Numbers table been causing this? I only actuall need maximum 60 iterations, 10k numbers might not be necessery ha?

Comment: @EMRE Do one check and share result: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
           [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton X 
CROSS JOIN [Mainfiles].[dbo].[Numbers3]
LEFT JOIN  [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton Y 
       ON (X.SOZLESMENO = Y.SOZLESMENO)
      AND (DATEADD(MONTH, - H, X.YRMONTH) = Y.YRMONTH)
      AND H BETWEEN 1 AND @iteration_limit` How many rows is generated

Comment: @lad2025 I cant make the middle line between columns to appear. do you add those by hand?

Comment: @EMRE That table is your source table `x2Skeleton` or your desire output after update? You should always include both

Comment: @lad2025 even I fix number of iterations as 1 instead of 60 that sanity check you provided takes forever to run, there is something fundamentally inefficient here :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza until the statusTest_toBe it is the source table, the right-most column is what I want to get after the query

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza All data has to be tab delimited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express what you want using window functions.  If `StatusTest_AsIs` is always increasing, you can just use `max()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select X.*, max(StatusTest_AsIs) over (partition by SOZLESMENO order by YRMONTH) as new_statusTest_ToBE
      from [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton X
     )
update toupdate
    set statusTest_ToBE = new_statusTest_ToBE
    where statusTest_ToBE <> new_statusTest_ToBE;
```

If the values are not increasing, you can still do this.  Getting the previous non-NULL value is a bit tricky, but `APPLY` is a good way to do it:

```
with toupdate as (
      select X.*, x2.StatusTest_AsIs as new_statusTest_ToBE
      from [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton x cross apply
           (select top 1
            from  [Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton x2
            where x2.SOZLESMENO = x.SOZLESMENO and x2.YRMONTH <= YRMONTH and
                  x2.StatusTest_AsIs is not null
            order by YRMONTH desc
           ) x2
     )
update toupdate
    set statusTest_ToBE = new_statusTest_ToBE
    where statusTest_ToBE <> new_statusTest_ToBE;
```

For both these queries, but this one in particular, you want an index on `[Mainfiles].dbo.x2Skeleton(SOZLESMENO, YRMONTH, StatusTest_AsIs)`.

Comment: I have used the first option (increasing one) by manipulating my data (instead of using `max(StatusTest_AsIs)` I generated a unique increasing code for the `non-NULL` values of `StatusTest_AsIs`. The point is not actually changing this and that variable.  It is the **Window functions**, which are awesome and perfect fit for these situations. Opened up new horizons to me. _Thanks a lot_