# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' in DELETE query SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I just wrote this `DELETE` query in SQL Server 2012 and I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

when I execute it. Can anyone help?

```
DELETE FROM Nhanvien 
INNER JOIN Hoadon ON Nhanvien.MaNV = Hoadon.MaNV
WHERE YEAR(Ngaysinh) = '1994'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs2sf.png)

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DELETE FROM FROM` more info **[`Why does DELETE FROM … FROM … not error out`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33041791/why-does-delete-from-from-not-error-out/33041916#33041916)**:

```
DELETE 
FROM #Nhanvien
FROM #Nhanvien
JOIN #Hoadon ON #Nhanvien.MaNV=#Hoadon.MaNV
WHERE YEAR(Ngaysinh)='1994';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391792)**</kbd>

---

You can skip first `FROM` and use:

```
DELETE #Nhanvien
FROM #Nhanvien
JOIN #Hoadon ON #Nhanvien.MaNV=#Hoadon.MaNV
WHERE YEAR(Ngaysinh)='1994';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391793)**</kbd>

*Warning*

You should prefix `Ngaysinh` column with table name. I've assumed it is from `#Nhanvien` table in my demos.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it have a new error in **MaNV**, "invalid column name MaNV".
Is that error happens because of my constraint in database?

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Error message? Share **`CREATE TABLE`** script for both tables

Comment: @ĐinhQuân You don't have this column in one of the tables, probably this column has different name

Comment: Here: 
`CREATE TABLE Nhanvien (MaNV int NOT NULL, TenNV nvarchar(30), Diachi nvarchar(20), Ngaysinh Datetime, SDT varchar(11));
CREATE TABLE Hoadon (MaHd int NOT NULL, MaKh int NOT NULL, MaNV int NOT NULL, Ngaylap Datetime);`

Comment: No, when I write "delete from..." the column "Hoadon.MaNV" is available but the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER' happens, then when I write "delete Nhanvien from..."  like you said, the column "Hoadon.MaNV" become invalid

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Show your entire query

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Do you know you can post images/text editing your initial question. Also your link to google drive require logging. Just paste text

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Do you remove all `#` from my demos?

Comment: sure I remove all **#**

Comment: sorry for my bad, can we chat vial skype or another applications, i want to show my problem easier

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Make screenshot of Mangament Studio that contains query and error and post to your question using (add image) (CTRL + G)

Comment: @ĐinhQuân Did you read my answer second part? `DELETE Nhanvien
FROM Nhanvien
JOIN Hoadon ON #Nhanvien.MaNV=Hoadon.MaNV
WHERE YEAR(Ngaysinh)='1994';`

Comment: yes I was do like you said but when change to `DELETE Nhanvien` , the column `Hoadon.MaNV` become invalid

Comment: Thank you for your help lad2025, I did it, my database have not complete yet so it have other problem with thís `DELETE` your **livedemo2** was right.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly define which table you are deleting from:

```
DELETE n 
FROM Nhanvien n
INNER JOIN Hoadon h ON n.MaNV = h.MaNV
WHERE YEAR(n) = '1994'
```

Comment: Thank you, I want to delete the person's information on table "Nhanvien" have born in 1994,btw the table "Hoadon" have a Foreign key to table "Nhanvien" on "MaNV"- the person's ID. So I cannot understand why it  have error.

Comment: much easier answer to remember for daily use.